# How to format the excel cells while exporting from C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, datatable

I Wrote a program to export the excel from data table in C#. By default, the cell format is fixed in **General**. How to change the cell format through program? (*Example format : **Text , Number** etc*).
Here is my code

```
        private void WriteExcel(DataTable datatable, string FileName)
        {
            StringBuilder SBuild = new StringBuilder();
            using (StreamWriter sw2Excel = File.CreateText(FileName))
            {
                //get the Columns of the DataTable in the 1st Line
                for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    SBuild.Append(datatable.Columns[i].ColumnName + "\t");
                }
                sw2Excel.WriteLine(SBuild.ToString());
                //Fill The Rows To the Excel File
                for (int i = 0; i < datatable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    StringBuilder swRowSb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int k = 0; k < datatable.Columns.Count; k++)
                    {
                        swRowSb.Append(datatable.Rows[i][k].ToString().Replace(',', ' ') + "\t");
                    }
                    sw2Excel.WriteLine(swRowSb.ToString());
                }
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook = app.Workbooks.Open(FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, ",", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                workBook.SaveAs(FileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing
                , Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                app.Workbooks.Close();
                app.Quit();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good article on excel cell formatting [here](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-format-excel.htm)

proposed changes to your code - note below code is untested and based on the article

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet.Range cellRange = workSheet.get_Range("a1", "z256")

//change to text format
cellRange.NumberFormat = "@";
```